# Datas com php google charts

Tags: php, data

Preciso pegar a data e colocar em um gráfico do `Google Chart`, exemplo:
Vendas hoje, essa semana, esse mês.

```
$sql = "SELECT dataCaptura FROM produtos";
//Trazendo resultados da tabela
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
//Condição para formar gráfico
$cont_hoje = date('d');
$cont_semana =date('w');
$cont_mes =date('m')

while($linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    if($linha['dataCaptura'] == date('d')){
        $cont_hoje++;
    }

    else if ($linha['dataCaptura'] =='date('w')){
        $cont_semana++;
    }
    else if ($linha['dataCaptura'] =='date('m')){
        $cont_mes++;
    }
}           

?>
```

mas não consigo fazer mostrar a quantidade de vendas feita hoje.

Comment: tem aspas a mais nos dois _elses_.. pode ser esse o problema?? `=='date(...)`

Comment: Corrigido, mas sem exito, eu quero pegar a quantidade que foi vendido hoje atraves da data, mas o unico valor que ele me dá é o numero da data de hoje e não a quantidade de itens que foram vendidos hoje.